# SQLite Query not getting actual count

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with getting the count of the total passenger and baggage on the specific place.

This is my table,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN9Om.png)

but my `query` shows the total passenger is always 2,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDpOF.png)

and lastly, this is the `query`

```
select
    ticket_placeto,
    (select count(*) as count from tickets where passenger_type <> 'Baggage' group by ticket_placeto)as Pass ,
    ifnull((select count(*) as count from tickets where passenger_type = 'Baggage' group by ticket_placeto),0) as Baggage
from tickets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrase your query to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    ticket_placeto,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type <> 'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Pass,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN passenger_type =  'Baggage' THEN 1 END) AS Baggage
FROM tickets
GROUP BY ticket_placeto;
```

The idea here is that for each `ticket_placeto` group you want to take two conditional counts depending on the passenger type.

Comment: it returns an error on chrome://inspect `unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.`

Comment: @MikeNeriesGorospe Then you have some other problem most likely not related to my query.  What I wrote above should run on SQLite without any problem.

Comment: Hi its working on android studio but not in `chrome://inspect` thank you